# Removing Portions of an Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, google-maps

I am making an app to lookup/navigate to certain locations. I have this code and am trying to remove the ',0' part at the end of the coordinates in order to make it compatible with Google maps. I would go through and do it manually but I have a couple thousand locations that I have to deal with so that is impracticable. I have tried to use the .splice() method to no avail.

```
$scope.SiteLocs = [{
        "name": "502 Nelson St, Greenville, MS 38701",
        "visibility": "0",
        "description": "502 Nelson St, Greenville, MS 38701",
        "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
        "Point": {
          "coordinates": "-91.05636,33.415485,0"
        }

      }, {
        "name": "242 Blackhawk Trace, Galena, IL 61036",
        "visibility": "0",
        "description": "242 Blackhawk Trace, Galena, IL 61036",
        "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
        "Point": {
          "coordinates": "-90.319778,42.390862,0"
        }
      }, {
        "name": "3747 Ocean Dr, Vero Beach, FL 32963",
        "visibility": "0",
        "description": "3747 Ocean Dr, Vero Beach, FL 32963",
        "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
        "Point": {
          "coordinates": "-80.358248,27.659094,0"
        }
```

Comment: By the way, `splice()` is not a method of strings

Comment: What is your problem when using splice to delete a part of an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the loop and check if any last two characters are ",0" if yes remove them.
 http://jsbin.com/yodeg/2/edit

```
$scope.SiteLocs = [
   {
  "name": "502 Nelson St, Greenville, MS 38701",
  "visibility": "0",
  "description": "502 Nelson St, Greenville, MS 38701",
  "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
  "Point": {
    "coordinates": "-91.05636,33.415485,0"
  }

}
   , 
   {
  "name": "242 Blackhawk Trace, Galena, IL 61036",
  "visibility": "0",
  "description": "242 Blackhawk Trace, Galena, IL 61036",
  "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
  "Point": {
    "coordinates": "-90.319778,42.390862,0"
  }
}
   , 
   {
  "name": "3747 Ocean Dr, Vero Beach, FL 32963",
  "visibility": "0",
  "description": "3747 Ocean Dr, Vero Beach, FL 32963",
  "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
  "Point": {
    "coordinates": "-80.358248,27.659094,0"
  }
   }];

 angular.forEach($scope.SiteLocs, function(location){



    var clength = location.Point.coordinates.length;

   // if last 2 characters in string are ",0"
    if (location.Point.coordinates.substring(clength-2,clength)===",0")
    {
      location.Point.coordinates = location.Point.coordinates.substring(0,clength-2);

    }

  });
```

Comment: In your jsbin, what does ' <pre>{{SiteLocs|json}}</pre> ' do?

Comment: It is useful for testing shows you your object in json format

Comment: This is odd. I cant figure out why your code works in jsbin but not on my plunker. You think you could take a look for me? http://plnkr.co/edit/OZZRgiEcrLzreW3lrc5v?p=preview

Comment: please see http://plnkr.co/edit/ZKgKfTWtW4inZDq7lFC5?p=preview angular.forEach ... was outside controller. Huge array of locations by the way :)

Comment: and is everything ok ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Angular (playing with plain JS, adjust accordingly) but shouldn't this work?

```
SiteLocs.forEach(function(location){
  location.Point.coordinates = location.Point.coordinates.slice(0,-2);
});
```